# Unable to Find last Row and paste the content to the end

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to iteratively take input from Column 'D' of Sheet 1  of Workbook 'A' and searching the text in 'Allocation' worksheet of Workbook B .Then, if text is found I intend to copy those cells from  workbook 'A' and pasting under the first found empty row below existing data in another Worksheet named as 'All_Records' of workbook 'A'.

The below code sourced from web works fine but it is pasting the extracted cells from Workbook B by overwriting the previously pasted rows.

I have tried loop through but with my limited knowledge on VBA , I am unable to do so. Can someone please help me out with my problem set.

```
Sub SearchFolders()

    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xStrSearch As Range
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xStrFile As String
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWk As Worksheet
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xFound As Range
    Dim xStrAddress As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    'On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Set xStrSearch = Sheet1.Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In xStrSearch
    MsgBox cell.Value

    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set xOut = Worksheets("All")


    xRow = 1

    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsm")


        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(cell)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        'xRow = xRow + 1
                        Dim LastRow As Integer

                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Value
                        .Cells(xRow, 4) = xFound.Offset(, 5).Value

                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
    End With
    'MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "Mssg Box"


    Next



End Sub
```

I want all extracted data to be pasted into the worksheet B row- wise after finding empty row in worksheet A

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you expect it to, the main thing I've added is:

```
 NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
 'find the next available row in Column A
 .Cells(NextRow, 1) = xWb.Name
 .Cells(NextRow, 2) = xWk.Name
 .Cells(NextRow, 3) = xFound.Value
 .Cells(NextRow, 4) = xFound.Offset(, 5).Value
```

Which will find the next available row and enter the data in those cells:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
Dim xFso As Object
Dim xFld As Object
Dim xStrSearch As Range
Dim xStrPath As String
Dim xStrFile As String
Dim xOut As Worksheet
Dim xWb As Workbook
Dim xWk As Worksheet
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xFound As Range
Dim xStrAddress As String
Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim xCount As Long
Dim cell As Range

Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"

If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
    xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
End If

If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set xStrSearch = Sheet1.Range(Range("D2"), Range("D2").End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each cell In xStrSearch
    MsgBox cell.Value

    Set xOut = Worksheets("All")

    xRow = 1

    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 3) = "Cell"
        .Cells(xRow, 4) = "Text in Cell"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsm")

        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(cell)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else
                        xCount = xCount + 1

                        NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
                        .Cells(NextRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(NextRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(NextRow, 3) = xFound.Value
                        .Cells(NextRow, 4) = xFound.Offset(, 5).Value

                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Offset(1).Select
    End With
    'MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "Mssg Box"
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @Xabier. The above inputs from you worked for me, like a charm. Cheers !!

Comment: @JobSeeker Please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks. :)